# Having sum values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume the following sample data:

```
a   |   b  |    c   |  d    |  e   |  f
-----------------------------------------
400 | 1200 |    1   | 500   |  1   |  200
400 | 1200 |    1   | 500   |  1   |  200
400 | 1200 |    1   | 500   |  1   |  200
400 | 1200 |    1   | 500   |  1   |  200
400 | 1200 |    2   | 300   |  3   |  300
400 | 1200 |    2   | 300   |  3   |  300
401 | 800  |    3   | 100   |  4   |  100
401 | 800  |    4   | 100   |  NULL|  NULL
402 | 300  |   NULL | NULL  |  NULL|  NULL
```

I want to have my output contain one record for each value of column a and b, and also sum of column d by distinct c.  So, my end result should look like this:

```
400 | 1200 | 800 | 500
400 | 800  | 200 | 100
401 | 300  | NULL| NULL
```

is there any specific statement for doing this in SQL?

Comment: Can explain how expected result comes?

Comment: I want to have one record for each value of column a and b and also sum of d column by distinct c,

Comment: Actually I have more columns,e f g ...,so i cant have a,b,sum(d),

Comment: I mean for this data:

a b  c d e f
400 1200  1 500 1 200
400 1200  1 500 1 200
400 1200  1 500 1 200
400 1200  1 500 1 200
400 1200  2 300 3 300
400 1200  2 300 3 300
401 800  3 100 4 100
401 800  4 100 NULL NULL
401 300 NULL NULL NULL NULL

 I want to have this result :

400 1200  800 500
401 800  200 100
402 300  NULL NULL

Comment: How is the value rows appear twice  `400 1200 800` and `400 800     200`?

Comment: Still not clear your requirement

Comment: excuse me,I edited my question

Comment: @MaryamBahramfar Your sample has 6 columns, your result has 4. how can we know, what you want to to? It SEEMS as if you are looking for aggregate functions, please put some more effort in searching for other questions, there are tons on stackoverflow as well as "on" google

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sum` aggregate with `Distinct`

```
select a,b,sum(distinct d),sum(distinct f) 
From yourtable
Group by a,b
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query return your expected result:

```
SELECT a, b, SUM(Dval) AS d
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, SUM(DISTINCT d) Dval
    FROM Testtable
    GROUP BY a, b, c
) R
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a
```

Actual execution with the sample data:

```
DECLARE @Testtable TABLE (a INT, b INT, c INT, d INT);

INSERT INTO @Testtable (a, b, c, d) VALUES 
(400, 1200, 1, 500),
(400, 1200, 1, 500),
(400, 1200, 1, 500),
(400, 1200, 1, 500),
(400, 1200, 2, 300),
(400, 1200, 2, 300),
(401, 800 , 3, 100),
(401, 800 , 4, 100),
(402, 300 , NULL, NULL);

SELECT a, b, SUM(Dval) AS d
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, SUM(DISTINCT d) Dval
    FROM @Testtable
    GROUP BY a, b, c
) R
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: yes I know that i can do this, but I have more columns as I edited question, so i want to know does sql has specific statement for it or not?

Comment: `SUM(DISTINCT` is the key here. I don't know any other special way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you desired result:

```
SELECT  a,
        SUM(DISTINCT b) b,
        SUM(d) d
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT a,
                    b,
                    c,
                    d
    FROM YourTable
    ) t
GROUP BY a
```

In sub-query we get rows without duplicates, then GROUP BY a with aggregation.

**EDIT**

For your new recordset - same rules:

```
SELECT  a,
        SUM(DISTINCT b) b,
        SUM(d) d,
        SUM(DISTINCT f) f
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT a,
                    b,
                    c,
                    d,
                    e,
                    f
    FROM YourTable
    ) t
GROUP BY a
```

Output:

```
a   b       d       f
400 1200    800     500
401 800     200     100
402 300     NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a,b,sum(f),d
from [table name]
where c>0
group by a,b,d
```